# Gutenberg Block empty after reload of editor

Tags: visual-editor, block-editor

Well, everythings fine with this. editor and frontend works. but when i come back to pages edit screen, the block is empty.
i think there is an error with the attributes, but i can't find good documentation on this. can anybody help?

```
( function( blocks, editor, components, element, api ) {
    var el = element.createElement;
    var source = blocks.source;
    var InspectorControls = editor.InspectorControls;
    var RichText = editor.RichText;

    blocks.registerBlockType( 'efna-blocks/pdflinks', {
        title: 'PDF-Links',
        icon: 'media-default',
        category: 'common',
            attributes: {
                link: {
                    source: 'children',
                    selector: 'div'
                }
        },

        edit: function(props) {
                    var children = [];

                    function setHtml(element) {
                        props.setAttributes({link: element});
                    }

                    children.push(
                        el( 'div', null,
                            el( RichText, {
                                multiline: null,
                                formattingControls: ['link'],
                                onChange: setHtml,
                                tagName: 'div'
                            }, props.attributes.link )
                        )
                    );

                    return [
                        el( 'div', { className : props.className }, children )
                    ];
        },

            save: function( props ) {
                return el( 'div', { className : props.className },
                    el( RichText.Content, { className: 'pdf-link', value: props.attributes.link } )
                );
            }

        }
    );
})(
    window.wp.blocks,
    window.wp.editor,
    window.wp.components,
    window.wp.element,
    window.wp.api
);
```

resulting div block in frontend:

```
<div class="wp-block-efna-blocks-pdflinks">
 <a href="http://test.pdf">Das Dokument – technsiche Details</a><br>
 <a href="http://test.pdf">Das Dokument – technsiche Details</a><br>
 <a href="http://test.pdf">Das Dokument – technsiche Details</a><br>
 <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that currently the best place for these kinds of questions is actually the Gutenberg github issues, the number of people who can help there is significantly higher than here or anywhere else

Comment: but why? maybe we should bring more of the knowledge here. github is for development, not for support...

Comment: If you ask on github and post the answer here that works too, but Gutenberg knowledge hasn't had a chance to spread out yet, and the project is in flux. There's no guarantee that the knowledge exists here yet, it's all very new. For now though, the github issue tracker is superior

Comment: Having a similar issue in 2022, I for one appreciate this question, as Gutenberg has been all over the place (stick it in GitHub, keep the discussion to WordPress, use the docs etc) and _any_ info that points me in the right direction is appreciated, as the WordPress docs aren't quite there yet for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make your block save and load on refresh by changing the `edit` to so:

```
edit: function(props) {
    return [
        el(
            'div',
            { className : props.className },
            el( 'div', null,
                el( RichText, {
                    multiline: null,
                    formattingControls: ['link'],
                    onChange: function (element) {
                        props.setAttributes({link: element});
                    },
                    tagName: 'div',
                    value: props.attributes.link,
                } )
            )
        )
    ];
},
```

Notably, I removed the children array logic and placed `props.attributes.link` in `RichText`'s `value` instead of a third attribute on `el()`

Comment: works very well for me, thanks... would be really nice to have a good documentation for that.

Comment: I figured it out using the [RichText docs](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/94f54892c214ebd014ec126a9575b7e902198ad9/packages/editor/src/components/rich-text/README.md) which is also available in the [Gutenberg Handbook](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/block-api/rich-text-api/)